# What would a garbage collector do here?

Tags: c, memory-management, garbage-collection

I saw this bit of code in another thread

```
void foo {
  int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
  *n = 10; 
  n++;
  printf("%d", *n);
}
```

The mistake here is obvious. `n` isn't being dereferenced.
There is a memory leak.
Let's assume there is a garbage collector working here. The reference count to our initial value of `n` is zero now because `n` isn't referencing it anymore. So it's garbage and returned back. But what about the new location pointed by `n`? Technically this area of memory hasn't been allocated yet. So will the reference count be incremented here?

Comment: Are you thinking to the same imaginary garbage detector that I am thinking about ?

Comment: Why did the other guy remove his answer?

Comment: The program is not very likely to continue past printf, since you dereference an invalid pointer, GC or no GC.

Comment: @kaizer.se: memory is allocated in blocks, and the block _may_ be larger than amount of memory that was actually requested. So, the program might work just fine - depending on compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correctly implemented garbage collector would work as follows:

```
int *pi = malloc(sizeof int);
*pi = 10;
```

Everything's fine here.

```
pi++;
```

This statement lets `pi` point behind the allocated int, which is explicitly allowed by the ISO C99 standard (see 6.5.6p7, 6.5.6p8). Later in the code, there may be `pi--`, so the allocated int can still be accessed. Or it may be accessed by the expression `pi[-1]`, which is perfectly valid at this point.

```
pi = NULL;
```

At this point, there is no way to ever access the allocated int anymore, so the garbage collector may collect the memory.

In summary: All pointers that point either to the beginning of an object, to somewhere in the middle of that object or to the location behind that object can be used to access the object. So if such a value exists in memory, the object must not be garbage collected.

Comment: Well you can still do that if you implement your one GC, but 6.5.6p8 just says that the operation p+k must not overflow until allocated memory+2 so that you always have p + last_el < p + last_el + 1.  
Where p is an array.

Comment: What do you mean with "that? I didn't understand your statement.

And if 6.5.6p8 would not exist, the location after the allocated int (`pi + 1`) would probably be invalid, so that a pointer to this location would not be considered related to `pi`.

Comment: .. 6.5.6p8 precisely states that pi+1 is invalid:
"the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated"  
For me, the point of the paragraph is that the *addition* pi+1 must not overflow so that pi < pi+1. An overflow would make pi+1 < pi in some case, which is sad because you wont have the guarantee to have a strict upper bound address for your array. The paragraph doesn't state anything about a "relation" between pi and the allocated memory.

Comment: The expression `pi + 1` is valid (before incrementing it), but `*(pi + 1)` is not. And this is what 6.5.6p8 states precisely. The paragraph states that the expression `pi + 1` still represents a pointer that is related to the allocated int.

Answer (score 1):

C garbage collectors do not perform reference counting. They are typically mark-sweep, and they operate on blocks, not individual bytes. In your example, the gc would mark the block, not the address.  Even so, the core of your question is still valid:

**What does the *mark* phase do when it reaches a "bad" pointer?**
A *conservative* collector simply ignores it. The memory in the initial malloc will be collected.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my mind; I think yes. The problem is code like this:

```
int* n = malloc(sizeof(int));
n++;
int* o = n;
int* p = n;
n = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Now there are three references to the memory pointed to by `n`, but the garbage collector only sees one. Doing `n = NULL;` would cause a cleanup despite existing `o` and `p` pointers. Pointer flexibility like this is the main reason a C garbage collector is so difficult; I'm not sure it's possible to have a flawless garbage collector in C, as you can have pointers whose addresses aren't known until runtime